# undefined is not object React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-android

I am getting well known error undefined is not an object when trying to call **this.refs** from the context of navigationOptions.

Better if I explain with code:

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'my app',
        title: 'my app',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            textAlign: "center",
            flex: 1,
        },
        headerLeft:
            <TouchableOpacity style={{padding: 15, marginLeft: 5}} onPress={() => { navigation.state.params.goBack(navigation.state.params.canGoBack) }}>
                {navigation.state.params.canGoBack ? <Text>back</Text>: <Text>close</Text>}
            </TouchableOpacity>,
    });


    componentDidMount() {
            this.props.navigation.setParams({goBack: this.onBack});
            this.props.navigation.setParams({canGoBack: this.state.canGoBack});
            Keyboard.dismiss();
        }

   onBack(canGoBack) {
        console.log(canGoBack);
        if(canGoBack){
            this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].goBack(); // here is the error happening, somehow I can access this.refs.
        }
    }

    onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
        this.setState({
            canGoBack: navState.canGoBack
        });
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            canGoBack: this.state.canGoBack,
        });
        console.log("some action happened: " + this.state.canGoBack);

    }
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: It's not bound and being called outside of the object's context.

Comment: You can use arrow function in order to get correct context: `onBack = (canGoBack) =>  { <access this.refs> }`

Comment: You can even assign a constant as `const instance = this;` in the start of your function and use `instance.refs`. It's occurring because scope of `this` is undefined in callback functions. So define a variable containing `this` and use it in callback function :)

Comment: @User97 thnx, it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are losing the context when using `this.onBack`

You need to make sure that `this.onBack` is called with your component context, and you can do this by either:

- Using `arrow functions`:  `this.props.navigation.setParams({goBack: (e) => this.onBack(e)});`
- Bind `this` to your function: `this.props.navigation.setParams({goBack:  this.onBack.bind(this)});`